# Symbolize Fusion Table on map based on date subtraction

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I need to symbolize a Fusion Table (points) on a Google Map - easy stuff. The trick here is that I need to symbolize the points based on the difference between now (today) and a date in a Fusion Table column.

My understanding is that the API can't do date subtraction (there is no 'now' in the API). A workaround for this is to do the subtraction in Excel with result in a new column, re-upload to Fusion Tables, and then symbolize based off the new result value. But that's only accurate *today* - Fusion Tables can only hold static information - so it isn't a very good solution.

Am I missing something here or anyone have any other ideas how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how complicated the styling you require is, you could do it dynamically using [dynamic scaling](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#fusion_table_styles), that option can only apply 5 different styles, but could be based on today's date, as that is available in the browser via javascript.

If you have more than 5 styles required, but don't have lots of points, you could also query the table for the data and add native Google Maps API v3 markers, that loses the tile based rendering advantage of FusionTableLayers, but would allow more styles.

Comment: But does dynamic styling support date subtraction? I haven't seen anything supporting it, and the testing I have done hasn't worked.

Comment: Dynamic styling can be based on a javascript date subtraction.  You have a column containing a date, do something like "where: "date_column > "+today2Fusion(); and write the today2Fusion(0 function to get today's date and convert it into the format required for the comparison.